# How to execute a task in gradle 6

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have the following lines of code in build.gradle, from gradle 4:

```
task processP1AndP2(dependsOn: assemble) {
processP1.execute();
processP2.execute();
```

}

```
task processP1() {
jsFiles = [
        file(dir + "/js/util/common.js"),
        file(dir + "/js/util/clone.js"),
        file(dir + "/js/util/compare.js"),
]
cssSFiles = [
        file(dir + "/css/app.css"),
        file(dir + "/css/datatables-checkboxes.css")
]
inputFolder = file("${projectDir}/src/main/resources/templates/assets/app")
cssOutputFile = file("${buildDir}/resources/main/templates/css/app.min.css")
jsOutputFile = file("${buildDir}/resources/main/templates/js/app.min.js")
resourcesFoldersToCopy = ['images', 'fonts']
}

configure(processP1) {
    group = 'Resources'
    description = 'CSS & JS files.'
}
```

I want to upgrade to gradle 6, but the execute method doesn't exist anymore and I don't know how to rewrite the lines to compile in gradle 6. Thank you all!

Comment: Please provide how task `processP1` and task `processP2` are defined.

Comment: I have edited the post with the definition of processP1. Task processP2 has a similar definition

Comment: The way the task is defined indicates that it is a [DefaultTask](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/DefaultTask.html) type. But the properties on the task such as `jsFiles`, `cssOutputFile` are not part of `DefaultTask`. This leads me to believe you are configuring something else. Are able to provide a minimal snippet of the full Gradle file including any applied plugins?